# Sort tuple data

Tags: python

I have two tuple

```
tuple1 = ('number', 'name', 'type', 'salary')
```

and

```
tuple2 = ('number', 'salary', 'name' 'type')
         (1, 13000, 'Danya', 'designer')
         (2, 15000, 'Lubov', 'programmer')
         (3, 20000, 'Nastya', 'seo')
```

I need:

1. change order
2. make order as tuple1
   like this example:

   ```
   tuple2 = ('number', 'name', 'type', 'salary')
            (1, 'Danya', 'designer', 13000)
            (2, 'Lubov', 'programmer', 15000)
            (3, 'Nastya', 'seo', 20000)
   ```

I made it statically, but I can't dynamically, are there any similar examples?

Comment: Your tuple has four different elements without any separation by commas.. Are you having a tuple inside list ?

Comment: What is your input? What is your expected output? What is the static version of your solution? What part of making it dynamic is unclear?

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you have a list of tuples like this:

```py
tuple = [('number','salary','name','type'),
         (1,13000,'Danya','designer'),
         (2, 15000, 'Lubov', 'programmer'),
         (3, 20000, 'Nastya', 'seo')]
```

In this case you can do the following:

```py
tuple = [(num, name, t, s) for num, s, name, t in tuple]
print(tuple)
[('number', 'name', 'type', 'salary'),
(1, 'Danya', 'designer', 13000),
(2, 'Lubov', 'programmer', 15000),
(3, 'Nastya', 'seo', 20000)]
```